# Cannot set Owner property to a Window that has been closed: Exception

Tags: wpf, mvvm-light

I use WPF 4.0 amd MVVM LIght ToolKit, i have following code:

```
public partial class View1: Window
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the FavoritesView class.
    /// </summary>
    public View1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {    
        Messenger.Default.Register<NotificationMessage>(this,
            (msg) =>
            {
                if (msg.Notification == "OpenDocument")
                {
                    DocumentView view = new DocumentView();
                    view.Owner=this;
                    view.ShowDialog();
                }
            });            
    }
}
```

When i many times open-close DocumentView window i get exception "Cannot set Owner property to a Window that has been closed". Why? Any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

You could try to unregister from NotificationMessage to avoid future executions.

```
Messenger.Default.Unregister(this);
```

Answer (score 2):

you need to Unregister from the message on the window closed event.
This will make sure that duplicate registration does not happen when a new instance is created.

```
private void Window_Closed(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{ 
   Messenger.Default.UnRegister<NotificationMessage>(this);
}
```